# Preciso retornar uma td vazia caso houver dados no banco

Tags: php

Galera, vou tentar ser específico aqui, preciso exibir todas as categorias e subcategorias de nível 1, 2 e 3 que existem no banco.

Consegui isso até agora, mas quando ele não acha nada no banco referente, ele quebra o html. Alguém poderia me dar um auxilio?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código até então está assim.

```
<tr>


    <!--CHAMANDO CATEGORIA-->
    <?php
    $select_cat = "SELECT * FROM categoria_recursiva WHERE nivel = 0";
    $res_selectCat = $conn->query($select_cat);
    while($colCat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_selectCat)):
        $idCat = $colCat['id'];
    ?>
    <td> <?= $colCat['nome']; ?> </td>

    <!--CHAMANDO A SUBCATEGORIA 1-->
    <?php
    $select_subcat1 = "SELECT * FROM categoria_recursiva WHERE id_pai = $idCat";
    $res_selectSub1 = $conn->query($select_subcat1);
    while($colSub1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_selectSub1)):
            $idSub1 = $colSub1['id'];
    ?>
        <td> <?= $colSub1['nome']; ?> </td>

    <!--CHAMANDO A SUBCATEGORIA 2-->
    <?php
        $select_sub2 = "SELECT * FROM categoria_recursiva WHERE id_pai = '$idSub1'";
        $res_selectSub2 = $conn->query($select_sub2);
        while($colSub2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_selectSub2)):
            $idSub2 = $colSub2['id'];
        ?>
        <td> <?= $colSub2['nome'];?> </td>

            <!--CHAMANDO A SUBCATEGORIA 3-->
            <?php
            $select_sub3 = "SELECT * FROM categoria_recursiva WHERE id_pai = '$idSub2'";
            $res_selectSub3 = $conn->query($select_sub3);
            while($colSub3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_selectSub3)):
                $idSub3 = $colSub3['id'];
                ?>
                <td> <?= $colSub3['nome'];?> </td>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>





    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#painel-editar<?= $colCat['id']; ?>" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#painel-remover<?= $col_cat['id']; ?>" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Apagar"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> </button>
    </td>
</tr><?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Coloque o código, não uma imagem do mesmo. O site tem suporte para isso.

Comment: Aparentemente o número de `<td>` está diferente pra cada  `<tr>` na sua tabela.

Comment: acabei de editar subindo o codigo

Answer (score 0):

Como você faz 3 consultas diferentes, também tem quantidade diferentes de resultados, e como cada célula da sua tabela é um resultado, você acaba com cada linha da sua tabela com número de células diferentes.

O ideal é que você pense numa consulta que já traga os dados do jeito que você quer, inclusive com com as categorias vazias, além de tornar sua vida mais simples, vai deixar sua página mais rápida (já que não vai precisar ir no banco 3 vezes), fiz o que eu imagino que seria o select que você precisa, se não for, você pode fazer os ajustes, o objetivo é só dar a ideia do que fazer:

```
SELECT cp.id, cp.nome as catpai, sc1.nome as subcat1, sc2.nome as subcat2, sc3.nome as subcat3
FROM categoria_recursiva cp
LEFT JOIN categoria_recursiva sc1 ON sc1.id_pai = cp.id
LEFT JOIN categoria_recursiva sc2 ON sc2.id_pai = sc1.id
LEFT JOIN categoria_recursiva sc3 ON sc3.id_pai = sc2.id
WHERE cp.id_pai is null -- para saber que cp vai ser apenas da categoria pai
```

A partir daqui você precisa de apenas um while para criar a tabela:

```
<?php
query($select_cat); // $select_cat é o sql acima
while($colCat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_selectCat)):
?>
<tr>
    <td> <?= $colCat['catpai']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?= $colCat['subcat1']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?= $colCat['subcat2']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?= $colCat['subcat3']; ?> </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#painel-editar<?= $colCat['id']; ?>" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#painel-remover<?= $colCat['id']; ?>" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Apagar"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```